# How can i put pending intents in SQlite databse?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-alarms

I am making an alarm application in android. I have used different pending intents for all type of alarms(monday,tuesday etc) , repeating alarm or single alarm. Now in my application the user can set any number of alarms for which i am using SQlite database.
My question is how can i put the details of my alarms in the SQlite database or how can put all the pending intents in the database?

This is my code for alarms:

case R.id.buttonSetAlarm:

```
        if(onealarm == true)
        {
            onealarm();
        }

        else if(repeatingalarm == true)
        {
            if(all == true||(monday==true && tuesday==true && wednesday==true && thursday==true && friday==true && saturday==true && sunday==true))
            {   alldaysalarm();
                monday=false;
                tuesday=false;
                wednesday=false;
                thursday=false;
                friday=false;
                saturday=false;
                sunday=false;
                }

            else if(monday==false && tuesday==false && wednesday==false && thursday==false && friday==false && saturday==false && sunday==false && all==false)
             {Toast.makeText(Alarm.this, "Alarm Cannot Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

        else
        {
        if(monday == true)
        {mondayalarm();}

        if(tuesday == true)
        {tuesdayalarm();}

        if(wednesday == true)
        {wednesdayalarm();}

        if(thursday == true)
        {thursdayalarm();}

        if(friday == true)
        {fridayalarm();}

        if(saturday == true)
        {saturdayalarm();}

        if(sunday == true)
        {sundayalarm();}

        }
        }
        if(radioButtonOneAlarm.isChecked()||radioButtonRepeatingAlarm.isChecked())
        {
        finish();
        }
        else
        {
        Toast.makeText(Alarm.this,"Please Set One Type Of Alarm \n Or Press Back To Go To Previous Menu"  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        finish();
        break;
    }   
        }

public void alldaysalarm()
{   alarmmanageralarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            if (calendar.compareTo(calendar1) <= 0) 
               {
               calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
               }
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.crazyyalarm.MyServiceAlarm");
PendingIntent pendingintentalarm = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
alarmmanageralarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),86400000 ,pendingintentalarm);
    Toast.makeText(Alarm.this, "Alarm Set For All Days", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String pi = pendingintentalarm.toString();
}

public void mondayalarm() 
{   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,2);
    repeating();
    PendingIntent pendingintentalarm2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 2, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmmanageralarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),604800000,pendingintentalarm2);
}

public void tuesdayalarm()
{   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);
    repeating();
    PendingIntent pendingintentalarm3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 3, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmmanageralarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),604800000 ,pendingintentalarm3);
}

public void wednesdayalarm()
{   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 4);
    repeating();
    PendingIntent pendingintentalarm4 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 4, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmmanageralarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),604800000 ,pendingintentalarm4);

}

public void thursdayalarm()
{   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
    repeating();
    PendingIntent pendingintentalarm5 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 5, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmmanageralarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),604800000 ,pendingintentalarm5);

    }

public void fridayalarm()
{   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
    repeating();
    PendingIntent pendingintentalarm6 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 6, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmmanageralarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),604800000 ,pendingintentalarm6);

    }

public void saturdayalarm()
{   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
    repeating();
    PendingIntent pendingintentalarm7 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 7, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmmanageralarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),604800000 ,pendingintentalarm7);

    }

public void sundayalarm()
    {   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        repeating();
        PendingIntent pendingintentalarm1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarmmanageralarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),604800000 ,pendingintentalarm1);

    }

public void onealarm()
{
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar = (Calendar) calendar1.clone();
    alarmmanageralarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);        
    if (calendar.compareTo(calendar1) <= 0) {
            // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.crazyyalarm.MyServiceAlarm");
    PendingIntent pendingintentalarm10 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 10, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    alarmmanageralarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingintentalarm10);
    Toast.makeText(Alarm.this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String pi = pendingintentalarm10.toString();
    }


public void repeating()
{
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar = (Calendar) calendar1.clone();
    alarmmanageralarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if(calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)>calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
    }
    if (calendar.compareTo(calendar1) <= 0) {

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
    }
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.crazyyalarm.MyServiceAlarm");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PendingIntent uses id and parameters, you can make a class that generates a unique id and assign it per intent, to store in databasse you need to store id and parameters and if you want history you can store whether intent is active or not otherwise you may want to delete intent record from database. so your simple database looks like this.

```
---------------------------
Intent
---------------------------
id (unique)
is_active
parameter_1
parameter_2
...
---------------------------
```

Comment: on the home screen of the application i want to show all the alarms in a list view.
And I want the name, time, and pending intent to be stored in the databse.
If i store the pending intent the database will i be able to update or delete the alarm for a particular time using that pending intent?
Also in my code you can see that i have created a new pending intent everytime. If i make the id unique every time can i use the same pending intent for all the alarm?

I am new to android development, that is why i am so confused right now.

Comment: you can update/override/cancel PendingIntent based on id, ex if you create an alarm with id of 500, you can modify/cancel it later using the id of 500.

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest you to create Alarm table and maintain all field information
>   as you required and eg.alarm to repeat mon,tue,etc..
>
> create record for every alarm and pass alarm record id as
>   pendingIntent request code and i suggest you to create alarm as given
>   below and cross verify in alarmReciever(BroadcastReciever) that alarm
>   record to push alarm activity screen for particular day in the week

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
        alarmIntent.setAction(IConstants.ACTION_SET_CLOCK_ALARM);//put your action
        alarmIntent.putExtra(IConstants.ALARM_REQUEST_CODE,alarm.getAlarmId());// pass alarm id
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,alarm.getAlarmId(), alarmIntent, 0);
        mgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time in millis,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

> ```
>   //alarmReciever
> ```

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if (/*alarm in this week day*/) {
            //push your alarm screen
        }
}
```

Comment: in your suggested code can i just use these two lines:

1.alarmIntent.setAction(IConstants.ACTION_SET_CLOCK_ALARM);//put your action
2.alarmIntent.putExtra(IConstants.ALARM_REQUEST_CODE,alarm.getAlarmId());// pass alarm id ?

And can i use a single pending intent with different id's for all my alarms? instead of creating a new pending intent everytime?

Comment: My code for alarm is working perfectly in my application.
But the user is able to set only one alarm right and when the user sets another alarm then it overwrites the previous alarm because there is no database in the application as of now.
My main problem is how i connect my alarms to the database?

Comment: pendingIntent with different REQUEST CODE is nothing but requesting mutiple pendingIntents(alarms)..

Comment: if user want multiple alarms then create one more record for that alarm and pass that record id to pendingIntent request code

Comment: You have used IConstants in the code.
what is this IConstant?

Comment: i have stored all constant in the class as IConsants for ease understanding